# openssl Could Not Find libcrypto-3-x64.dll

Tags: c++, openssl

I connected openssl to my project and it compiles and runs well, but next to the program after compiling there is a file **libcrypto-3-x64.dll**, without which the program will not run, so the question is **how do I use openssl without this dll** how to integrate it into the project?

**I found out what the problem is, with the dynamic library it does not exist, EVP_CIPHER_CTX_t ctx(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()); when I compile a program (static lib openssl) with this line there are so many errors unresolved external character (example __imp_getsockname)**

VERSION **3.0.5**

**I compiled the library according to this guide https://youtu.be/PMHEoBkxYaQ x64 static and still errors like this "unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError" "unresolved external symbol __imp_CertOpenStore.".**

Comment: Your program is dynamically linked to libcrypto, therefore it is needed at runtime. There is no way to run your program because this file contains necessary information that your program needs. You will either need to link with a static version of this library or ship it with your program.

Comment: I used "C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\lib" libraries from here and I understand they are dynamic. installed the package with vcpkg. found static but not sure what they are, "C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\openssl\x64-windows-rel" 
"libcrypto_static.lib" "libssl_static.lib" plugged them in and now the program is not compiling "unresolved external symbol __imp_WSAGetLastError".

Comment: How are you linking them?

Comment: @jackylamouette Linker - Additional Dependencies & C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\openssl\x64-windows-rel\libcrypto_static.lib & C:\vcpkg\buildtrees\openssl\x64-windows-rel\libssl_static.lib

Comment: check post i am edit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem and leave the answer here, just add 2 libraries in **Linker => Additional Dependencies**

```
Ws2_32.lib
Crypt32.lib
```